# Springboot version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

How can I check spring boot version compatibility issues?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the `System Requirement section` from the official Spring boot documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements

Note, it says `Tomcat 9.0`, but it also explicitly states support for `any Servlet 3.1+` container, which [Tomcat 8.5](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/index.html) is.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if Tomcat is compatible with the mentioned spring boot version look at [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements-servlet-containers)

In order to check which version is provided by spring boot itself, you can look at [spring-boot dependencies pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml)